# How to print only caller function in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to print caller function in Perl. Its displaying as per the expectation.

Below is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $a = 5;
my $b = fun1($a);

print "a:$a ** b:$b\n";

sub fun1 {
    my $r = shift;
    my $s = fun2($r);
    return $s;
}

sub fun2 {
    my $p = shift;
    print "the calling function is:", (caller 1)[3], "\n";
    print "and you're in:", (caller 0)[3], "\n";
    my $q = $p * 5;
    return $q;
}
```

Output:

```
the calling function is:main::fun1
and you're in:main::fun2
a:5 ** b:25
```

How can I print only `fun1` and `fun2` instead of `main::fun1` and `main::fun2` respectively.

If there is a way to print them according to I stated above its good. Or I would have to trim the result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```perl
my $name = $full_name =~ s/^.*:://sr;
```

Comment: Nice. Could be improves with a sentence on the `r` and `s` flags, imho, or how this woks for longer module names cause the regex is greedy.

Comment: `r` causes the modified value to be returned instead of working in-place. `s` makes `.` match any character.

Comment: thanks @ikegami. Well so there is no method to resolve this problem using `caller` itself?